# Is my solution O(n^2), if so, why is it running the same speed as O(n) solution

Tags: python, arrays, string, performance, loops

I did the leetcode problem.

https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        current = ""
        index = 0
        longest=0
        while index<len(s):
            if s[index] not in current:
                current += s[index]
                if longest < len(current):
                    longest = len(current)
            else:
                current += s[index]
                current = current[current.index(s[index])+1:index+1]
            index += 1 
            
        return longest
```

If I understand my code right, the worst case is if there are no duplicates, and current string goes from "" to s, and and check if s[index] not in current is the same as iterating throughout the entire string checking each character. so it should be 1 check, 2 checks, 3 checks and etc to len(s).
Which means worse case is (1/2)(n-1)(n) = n^2. Am I incorrect on any of this?

the following solutions the author claims is O(n)

```
class Solution:
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
    characters = set()
    left = right = ans = 0
    length = len(s)
    
    while right < length:
        if s[right] in characters:
            characters.remove(s[left])
            left += 1
        else:
            characters.add(s[right])
            right += 1
            ans = max(ans, right - left)
    
    return ans
```

However when I ran this, I found that it ran slightly slower then mine. 60 vs 64ms.

Is the sample size leetcode gives not large enough, and with a sufficiently large enough sample, his will be shown to be obviously faster then my own?

Comment: The best way to answer your question would be to run both versions with a larger and larger input strings and plot the times taken.  Then compare the shapes of the curves. You cannot get an empirical measure of complexity from a single data point.

Comment: I would expect so, as `s[index] not in current` is `O(n)`, but `s[right] in characters` is `O(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timing using random strings of increasingly longer lengths (per Stephen C comment).

**Test Code**

```
import perfplot
import string
import random

def poster(s: str) -> int:
    ' Poster Code '
    current = ""
    index = 0
    longest=0
    while index<len(s):
        if s[index] not in current:
            current += s[index]
            if longest < len(current):
                longest = len(current)
        else:
            current += s[index]
            current = current[current.index(s[index])+1:index+1]
        index += 1 

    return longest

def leetcode(s: str) -> int:
    ' From answer at Leetcode '
    characters = set()
    left = right = ans = 0
    length = len(s)
    
    while right < length:
        if s[right] in characters:
            characters.remove(s[left])
            left += 1
        else:
            characters.add(s[right])
            right += 1
            ans = max(ans, right - left)
    
    return ans


# Timing benchmark using perfplot i.e. https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/
out = perfplot.bench(
   setup=lambda n: ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k = n)) ,  # setup
    kernels=[
        poster,
        leetcode,
    ],
    labels=["poster", "leeetcode"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 18)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
out.show()   # Plot benchmarks
print(out)   # Print bencharks table
```

**Results**

- Both algorithms increase linearly with n i.e. O(n).
- Posted code is faster (almost twice as fast for n = 2**17 = 128K)

[image]

```
┏━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃   n    ┃  poster  ┃ leeetcode ┃
┃ (len)  ┃   (μs)   ┃    (μs)   ┃
┡━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ 2      │ 1400     │ 1800      │
│ 4      │ 2300     │ 2700      │
│ 8      │ 4400     │ 6200      │
│ 16     │ 7900     │ 11000     │
│ 32     │ 15200    │ 26500     │
│ 64     │ 27600    │ 50600     │
│ 128    │ 55800    │ 101400    │
│ 256    │ 106900   │ 203500    │
│ 512    │ 227300   │ 422700    │
│ 1024   │ 458900   │ 864000    │
│ 2048   │ 935700   │ 1751300   │
│ 4096   │ 1879700  │ 3545700   │
│ 8192   │ 3721100  │ 7094800   │
│ 16384  │ 7469500  │ 14325800  │
│ 32768  │ 14973600 │ 28527200  │
│ 65536  │ 29867900 │ 57391100  │
│ 131072 │ 59918300 │ 114634800 │
└────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Wow, I'm incredibly thankful you went through so much effort for this. Thanks! I really appreciate it. I'm thinking maybe it's n time, since the length of  the string current, does not scale to the length of s as there are only a finite number of possible characters. hence the longest length possible for current is actually 26. Therefore it's n time.